# Unexpected end of file assembly

Tags: assembly

This might be easy for you but I'm at beginner level for assembly language. I just downloaded tasm and my current problem is  **Fatal**program5.asm(11) Unexpected end of file encountered.

This is the program our teacher gave us:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.CODE

MAIN PROC
MOV AH, 2
MOV CX, 26
MOV DL, 41h

PRINT_LOOP:
INT 21H
INC DL
DEC CX
JNZ PRINT_LOOP

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Thanks!

Comment: I did it exactly as you've edited :( Idk why it's not working

Comment: Is your editor saving as unicode instead of ASCII, maybe?

Comment: That line number 11 is very suspicious too, check which one that is and maybe delete and re-type by hand (don't copy-paste).